# Customizing hostname in zsh prompt

Tags: zsh, prompt, oh-my-zsh

I am using zsh with oh my zsh and I wanted to get a thing like this:

[image]

How can I do it? I want a setting to put somewhere, so that whenever I restart my terminal and my system, it always displays the way a set it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PS1='%B%F{#ff1000}[%F{#d0b000}%n%F{#80f000}%b@%B%F{#00c0c0}%m %F{#ff80a0}%~%F{#ff1000}]%f%b$ '
```

Gives similar colour shades. Adapt to your taste.

- `%B`: bold (`%b` reverts to non-bold)
- `%F{#RRGGBB}` foreground colour specified with levels of red/green/blue in hexadecimal. (`%f` reverts to default colour). If your terminal doesn't support true-colour specifications but supports a 88 or 256 colour palette, run `zmodload zsh/nearcolor`.
- `%n` user name
- `%m` machine name (without domain part)
- `%~` current working directory with tilde representation where applicable.

See `info zsh 'prompt expansion'` for details.